# Chrome extension get all pagination pages items javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i have created chrome extention which must get all pagination pages items from aliexpress and put it all on first page.  I used jquery ajax to do this, but i get only firt page elements. is it possible to get several pagination pages elements with jquery ajax? or i need to use something different such as iframe?
i want something like this:
[HTML:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw87u.png)

```
<div  id="page2" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 1-->
<div  id="page3" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 2-->
<div  id="page4" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 3-->
<div id="page5" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 4-->
```

js:

```
let array = ['pageone, 'pagetwo', 'pagethree'....'lastpage']
let allpages = document.queryselectorALL(array).innerHTML;
document.body.append(allpages);
```

Comment: No, those elements are added when the page scripts run. They don't run when making a fetch/ajax request. You'd have to open that site in an iframe (or a tab).

Comment: How does it help me when i open it with iframe? and Will i can get each page items with iframe?

Comment: In an iframe (or tab) the site's scripts will run so you can send a `click` event on the "next page" element. Your content script that runs in this iframe/tab will read DOM and send a message with the extracted data to the background script.

Comment: can you show me some example code?